# Repeat commands with changes

Tags: bash, command-line, command-substitution

I have to repeat this command a lot of times a day, is there any way to execute it multiple times (aprox. 25 times)

```
cd ../folderName && ../../tools/clone.py
```

What I need to do is execute the clone script inside every folder I specify.

Comment: Wat exactly do you want? You can define an alias.

Comment: What I need to do is: execute the clone script inside each folder I specify

Comment: So what is wrong with defining an alias or a function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your shell profile or just try this one:

```
myclone () { cd $1; /full/path/to/clone.py }
```

And you can do

```
myclone ../folderName
```